# why is inoremap parentheses, brackets, quotes not working

Tags: vimrc, autocompletion

I'm new to vim and trying to configure vim for my coding learning course. I tried these very basic inoremap lines in my ~/.vimrc, and there are also similar lines for <>'", but none of them works.

```
inoremap { {}<ESC>i<left>
inoremap {<CR> {<CR>}<ESC>O
inoremap {{ {
inoremap {} {}
```

I even deleted all the lines in the .vimrc except these inoremap lines, still no effect, meaning when I hit {, I don't get its pair }. I know there are plugins that may be more powerful, but I don't want my .vimrc to be messy and become unmanageable therefore I'd really like the native features work out for me, as a starting point. After all I don't need very fancy functions at the moment.
Helps are appreciated.

By the way, I use FreeBSD, but I don't expect the vim configuration is so much system dependent.

Comment: If ypu keep only the first do you have the problem? One "problem' I see with your mapping is that it forces vim to wait for more keystroke to know what to do.

Comment: Yes. Keeping only first line gives me no difference, still no closing brace.

Comment: Could you add the ``set nocompatible`` line at the start of your ``.vimrc`` file?

Comment: Your first map would put cursor before `{`, while I think you want it to be inside curly braces. For that, following should do the job `inoremap { {}<ESC>i`

Comment: It seems to work fine on vim 8.2. Can you tell us which version of vim you are using? You can get that information by typing the command ``:version``

Comment: Hi, thank all for trying to offer help. It turns out the problem is with the system wide vimrc that I tweaked not long ago, which I think overrides the user level .vimrc. I just replaced the system wide vimrc with default one now the auto completion in ~/.vimrc works as desired.

Comment: To Maxim Kin, you are right. Thanks.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt `nocompatible` should not be necessary in a vimrc on recent-ish vims. `:help 'compatible'` (`when a vimrc or gvimrc file is found […], this option is switched off`)

Comment: @D.W if you have an answer please add it!

Comment: @Ben, ``set nocompatible`` is not strictly necessary but ``set cpoptions-=<`` is for the ``<Esc>``, ``<CR>`` and ``<Left>`` to work. I wanted to be sure a minimal working ``.vimrc``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem is with the system wide vimrc that I tweaked not long ago, which I think overrides the user level .vimrc. I just replaced the system wide vimrc with default one now the auto completion in ~/.vimrc works as desired. Don't know which settings in the /usr/local/etc/vim/vimrc were causing the problem though. Now I have following mapping lines in .vimrc:

```
inoremap { {}<ESC>i
inoremap {<CR> {<CR>}<ESC>O
inoremap {{ {
inoremap {} {}
```

Similar goes for []()"'.